# merge consecutive objects inside array with condition and update the merged elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

given an array of objects that represents a vehicle's paths sorted by date, what is the most efficient way of merging consecutive elements if :

- start_location_in_zone and end_location_in_zone are both true
- start_location_in_zone and end_location_in_zone are  both false

if objects got merged we update the array by :

- start_date = the start_date of the first merged element
- end_date = the end_date of the last merged element
- duration = sum of all merged duration
- start_index = the index of the first merged element in the old array
- end_index = the index of the last merged element in the old array
- state = "out_zone" if both false
- state = "in_zone" if both true

if element has start_location_in_zone and end_location_in_zone with diffrent boolean value :

- we keep it (no merge)
- start_index and end_index = index in the old array
- state = "to_zone" if (start_location_in_zone == false and end_location_in_zone == true)
- state = "from_zone" if (start_location_in_zone == true and end_location_in_zone == false)

example :

```js
[
    {
        "start_date": "2020-10-07T13:53:26.000",
        "end_date": "2020-10-07T14:55:49.000",
        "start_location_in_zone": false,
        "end_location_in_zone": false,
        "duration": 143000
    },
    {
        "start_date": "2020-10-07T15:53:26.000",
        "end_date": "2020-10-07T16:55:49.000",
        "start_location_in_zone": false,
        "end_location_in_zone": true,
        "duration": 7000
    },
    {
        "start_date": "2020-10-07T17:53:26.000",
        "end_date": "2020-10-07T18:55:49.000",
        "start_location_in_zone": true,
        "end_location_in_zone": true,
        "duration": 20000
    },
    {
        "start_date": "2020-10-07T19:53:26.000",
        "end_date": "2020-10-07T20:55:49.000",
        "start_location_in_zone": true,
        "end_location_in_zone": true,
        "duration": 30000
    },
    {
        "start_date": "2020-10-07T21:53:26.000",
        "end_date": "2020-10-07T22:55:49.000",
        "start_location_in_zone": false,
        "end_location_in_zone": false,
        "duration": 4200
    },
    {
        "start_date": "2020-10-07T23:53:26.000",
        "end_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:49.000",
        "start_location_in_zone": false,
        "end_location_in_zone": false,
        "duration": 4200
    }
]
```

Result:

```js
[{
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T13:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T14:55:49.000",
    "state": "out_zone",
    "duration": 143000,
    "start_index": "0",
    "end_index": "0"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T15:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T16:55:49.000",
    "state": "to_zone",
    "duration": 7000,
    "start_index": "1",
    "end_index": "1"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T17:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T19:55:49.000",
    "state": "in_zone",
    "duration": 50000,
    "start_index": "2",
    "end_index": "3"
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T21:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-08T00:10:49.000",
    "state": "out_zone",
    "duration": 8400,
    "start_index": "4",
    "end_index": "5"
  }
]
```

Comment: @pilchard yes it wasn't clear. gonna delete

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I tried a for loop and comparing i to i+1 and pushing the value to a new array every time then compare the value of the new array to the next value in the old array. it got too complicated too fast. I've deleted the code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good case for Reduce.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T13:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T14:55:49.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": false,
    "duration": 143000
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T15:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T16:55:49.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": true,
    "duration": 7000
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T17:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T18:55:49.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": true,
    "end_location_in_zone": true,
    "duration": 20000
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T19:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T20:55:49.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": true,
    "end_location_in_zone": true,
    "duration": 30000
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T21:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-07T22:55:49.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": false,
    "duration": 4200
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-07T23:53:26.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:49.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": false,
    "duration": 4200
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:49.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:50.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": false,
    "duration": 1
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:50.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:51.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": false,
    "duration": 2
  },
  {
    "start_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:51.000",
    "end_date": "2020-10-08T00:00:52.000",
    "start_location_in_zone": false,
    "end_location_in_zone": true,
    "duration": 12
  }
]


let previous = undefined
let mergedData = data.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  cur.start_index = i
  cur.end_index = i
  if (!previous) {
    previous = cur
    return acc
  }
  let isStartInZone  = previous.start_location_in_zone === previous.end_location_in_zone
  let isEndNotInZone = cur.start_location_in_zone === cur.end_location_in_zone
  let shouldMerge = isStartInZone && isEndNotInZone && previous.start_location_in_zone === cur.start_location_in_zone
  if (shouldMerge) {
    previous.end_date = cur.end_date
    previous.duration += cur.duration
    previous.end_index = i
    //acc.push(previous)
    //previous = undefined
    return acc
  }
  acc.push(previous)
  previous = cur
  return acc
}, [])
// handle left overs if last element is not merged
if (previous) mergedData.push(previous)
console.log(mergedData)
```

Comment: probably working as intended. Give me some time to understand the code. I always struggled to use reduce correctly.

Comment: after I tried more examples. this only merges the next element. if 5 consecutives are true/true, it won't' merge them together.

Comment: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
ft tt tt tt tt tt tt tt tt 
ff ff 
- >
ff ff ff ff ff ff 
ft tt tt tt tt 
ff

Comment: it should be ff ft tt ff

Comment: updated to perform multi merge - added some more test data to confirm